# Create onclick method with href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create **AJAX** versions of links where possible. For this I want to have a function replaceLinks which create a onClick handler for each link on the page which then calls `ajaxPageWSM(href)`. I have this:

```
function replaceLinks() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        ...
    });
}
```

How can I access the href inside the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the href like this:

```
function replaceLinks() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you even need anything other than `this.href`. So like:

```
function replaceLinks() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var href = this.href;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function replaceLinks() {
    $("a").on("click", function(event) {
       var href=event.currentTarget.href;
    });
}
```